# How to use excel vba to click on interactive dialog pop-up?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to use excel vba to navigate and export data from [this website](https://edap.epa.gov/public/single/?appid=73b2b6a5-70c6-4820-b3fa-186ac094f10d&sheet=807da6b7-4d65-48bc-8615-013e01dd61c4&opt=currsel&select=clearall). I am able to click on 2018, 2019 buttons and the setting option, but unable to click the 'export data' option with vba.  I attach my code below for your reference.

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub GetURLOfFrame()

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim webpage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://www.epa.gov/fuels-registration-reporting-and-compliance-help/rin-trades-and-price-information"
        Dim t As Date, ele As Object 'waiting
        Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10 '<==Adjust wait time

        While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        t = Timer
        Do
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
                Set ele = IE.document.getElementById("show-service-popup-dialog")
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            On Error GoTo 0
        Loop While ele Is Nothing
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

    Set webpage = IE.document
    Dim wkb As Workbook, wksRIN As Worksheet, wksFrames As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wksRIN = wkb.Sheets("RIN Trades and Prices")

    Dim Frame As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Set Frame = webpage.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(1)


    Dim URL As String
    URL = Frame.getAttribute("src") 'storing the link to the frame

    IE.navigate URL 'goes to the iframe site
        While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        t = Timer
        Do
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
                Set ele = IE.document.getElementById("content")
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            On Error GoTo 0
        Loop While ele Is Nothing
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

    Dim htmlarticle As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Set htmlarticle = webpage.getElementsByTagName("article")(0)

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    Dim buttons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Set buttons = htmlarticle.getElementsByClassName("lui-buttongroup ng-scope")(0).getElementsByTagName("button")
    buttons(buttons.Length - 2).Click 'clicking the second last year
    buttons(buttons.Length - 1).Click 'clicking the latest year

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    Dim SettingButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Set SettingButton = htmlarticle.getElementsByClassName("cl-icon cl-icon--cogwheel cl-icon-right-align")(0)
    SettingButton.Click

    Dim SettingOptions As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection, ExportDataButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement, button As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Set SettingOptions = webpage.getElementsByClassName("qv-contextmenu ng-scope")(0).getElementsByTagName("li")

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))

    Set ExportDataButton = webpage.getElementsByClassName("qv-contextmenu ng-scope")(0).getElementsByTagName("li")(0)
    ExportDataButton.Focus
    ExportDataButton.Click

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

When I run 'ExportDataButton.Click', nothing seems to happen and I am not sure the reason why. It is also not possible to scrape from the data in the table directly as the the values of innertext of the td are dynamic and changes as you scroll down the table.

[Unable to click on 'Export Data'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxxSZ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done a good job till the point you needed help. A tip at your code. Declare all variables in the head of the macro. That is more clearly and other people who read your code have a better focus.

I think it would be easier to take all values from the html table. But you've done good groundwork. So I completed your macro in the way you started. I commented on the code I added.

```
Sub GetURLOfFrame()

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim webpage As MSHTML.htmlDocument

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://www.epa.gov/fuels-registration-reporting-and-compliance-help/rin-trades-and-price-information"
        Dim t As Date, ele As Object 'waiting
        Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10 '<==Adjust wait time

        While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        t = Timer
        Do
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
                Set ele = IE.document.getElementById("show-service-popup-dialog")
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            On Error GoTo 0
        Loop While ele Is Nothing
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

    Set webpage = IE.document
    Dim wkb As Workbook, wksRIN As Worksheet, wksFrames As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wksRIN = wkb.Sheets("RIN Trades and Prices")

    Dim Frame As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Set Frame = webpage.getElementsByTagName("iframe")(1)


    Dim URL As String
    URL = Frame.getAttribute("src") 'storing the link to the frame

    IE.navigate URL 'goes to the iframe site
        While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        t = Timer
        Do
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
                Set ele = IE.document.getElementById("content")
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            On Error GoTo 0
        Loop While ele Is Nothing
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

    Dim htmlarticle As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Set htmlarticle = webpage.getElementsByTagName("article")(0)

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    Dim buttons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Set buttons = htmlarticle.getElementsByClassName("lui-buttongroup ng-scope")(0).getElementsByTagName("button")
    buttons(buttons.Length - 2).Click 'clicking the second last year
    buttons(buttons.Length - 1).Click 'clicking the latest year

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    Dim SettingButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Set SettingButton = htmlarticle.getElementsByClassName("cl-icon cl-icon--cogwheel cl-icon-right-align")(0)
    SettingButton.Click

    Dim SettingOptions As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection, ExportDataButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement, button As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Set SettingOptions = webpage.getElementsByClassName("qv-contextmenu ng-scope")(0).getElementsByTagName("li")

    'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05")) 'Not needed

    'The fifth li-tag is "Export data"
    Set ExportDataButton = webpage.getElementsByClassName("qv-contextmenu ng-scope")(0).getElementsByTagName("li")(4)
    'There is no focus and no click event
    'There are the two events keypress and qv-activate
    'We must trigger qv-activate to get the download popup
    '(See function TriggerEvent to understand what we do here)
    Call TriggerEvent(webpage, ExportDataButton, "qv-activate")
    'Give the popup time to raise
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    'I do it like you here, but it's much better to declare all variables in the head of the macro
    Dim lastIsDownloadLink As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    'The download link has the css class ng-binding. 101 elements has these css class
    'But the code for the popup is generated after clicking 'Export data' at the end of the HTML document
    'So we can be sure that the last element with the CSS class contains our searched link
    Set lastIsDownloadLink = webpage.getElementsByClassName("ng-binding")
    lastIsDownloadLink(lastIsDownloadLink.Length - 1).Click
    'Give the server time to generate the document and the IE to show the download button in the footer
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

    'Attention!
    'We have to use SendKeys to perform the download!!!
    'As long as the macro is running, keep your fingers away from the mouse and keyboard!!!
    '
    'I've tryed to use the URLDownloadToFile method from the urlmon.dll but that don't work
    'I'm sure the server blocks download questions from other applications than that one who
    'has generated the download url with. I tryed it also with FireFox and there comes the text,
    'that the requestet resource is not available. But the same link works at the same time in IE.
    'You will find the download in the download folder of your system
    Application.SendKeys ("%{S}")

    'IE.Quit
    'Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

This is the procedure to trigger a html event:

```
Private Sub TriggerEvent(htmlDocument As Object, htmlElementWithEvent As Object, eventType As String)

  Dim theEvent As Object

  htmlElementWithEvent.Focus
  Set theEvent = htmlDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  theEvent.initEvent eventType, True, False
  htmlElementWithEvent.dispatchEvent theEvent
End Sub
```